# Collection view alignment issue in different version

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview, storyboard

Collection view moves up in iOS 10.3.3. But work fine in iOS 11.0.
Can any one let me know how to fix this kind of issue which is realted with version

[image]

CollectionView Constrains.
[image]

```
UIStoryboard *storyBoard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
MSProductCategoryViewController
*msProductCategoryViewController = [storyBoard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"MSProductCategoryViewController"];
msProductCategoryViewController.title =titleName;
[self.navigationController pushViewController:msProductCategoryViewController animated:YES];
```

Comment: have you checked the constraints? It should not be ios Version issue

Comment: My Constrains fine!

Comment: Show your collection view constraints.

Comment: I don't think so. Please provide the collectionview constraints

Comment: I updated! please check the for constraints

Comment: @kiran So you're adding navigation controller programmatically?

Comment: Yes!  Its SecondViewController from Tabbarcontroller.

Comment: Add top spacing to of collectionview to be 44. Probably navigation bar is the issue.

Comment: If you don't have any other UI elements, I would recommend using UICollectionViewController instead of UIViewController with UICollectionView.

Comment: Its a trial version of development so i can go forward to say NO/YES for other UI elements, But i consider your recommendation!

Comment: Kiran pls use the collection view layout delegate methods for that.

Comment: set self.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = NO in your viewDidLoad

Comment: also try and uncheck for underTopBar in your viewController's extend edges attributes inspector.

Answer (score -1):

For CollectionView moving up issue please check if you have unselected the "Adjust Scroll View Insets" property of your ViewController in storyboard.

[Attributes Inspector of ViewController](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jv9mu.png)

You have added top constraint with 20 value. I assume you wanted to add top padding for collection view. If that is the reason then I suggest using "Section Insets" property of CollectionView.